# How to make python built-in functions support keyword arguments?

Tags: python, functional-programming

I want to use `partial()` to build a function that only takes one argument,
so that I can pass it to some high-order functions (ex: `map()`/`filter()`):

---

```
>>> from operator import sub
>>> from functools import partial

>>> map(lambda x:sub(x, 5), [1,2,3])
[-4, -3, -2]

>>> help(sub)
Help on built-in function sub in module operator:

sub(...)
    sub(a, b) -- Same as a - b.

>>> map(partial(sub, b=5), [1,2,3])
TypeError: sub() takes no keyword arguments
```

---

Is there some way to make `sub()`(or any other built-in functions) support keyword arguments?

Comment: Why do you need to use a keyword argument as opposed to a static argument. Why not 5 instead of b=5?

Comment: @CorbinMc: because then you cannot use a `functools.partial()` wrapper, that's why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a function defined in C does not take keyword arguments then there is no way to force it to do so. Either use `lamdba` and fill the arguments in the hard way, or wrap the function in a Python function that *can* take keyword arguments.